I do not know why my dark mode button does not have effect when trying to create a dark/light mode for my BTC tracking website
I have checked for the dark mode in local storage in the head of my 'index.html" document.
 <script>
        // Do this before the body gets parsed
        if (localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === '1') {
          document.documentElement.classList.add('darkmode');
        }
      </script>

I have also, tried including the source within the head and after the dark mode button of my "index.html" document.
<hr class="w-48 h-1 mx-auto my-4 bg-gray-100 border-0 rounded md:my-10 dark:bg-gray-700">
            <section style="display: grid; align-items: center; justify-content: center; min-height: 10vh; font-size: 2rem; padding-left: 17%; padding-right: 17%;">            
                <button class="inline-block border-2 border-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-3" id='darkToggle'>
                    <span class="light-only">dark</span>
                    <span class="dark-only">light</span>
                    mode
                </button>  
            </section>                      
        </div>
        <script src="src/landing.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

I have added an event listener in "landing.js" for this button to enable/disable dark mode.
document.querySelector('#darkToggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === '1'){
      localStorage.setItem('darkmode', '0')
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('darkmode')    
  }
  else if(localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === '0'){
      localStorage.setItem('darkmode', '1')
      document.documentElement.classList.add('darkmode')
  }
  });

My problem is that when I click onto the darkmode toggle button, nothing happens and the appearence does not change at all.
I tried console.log('testing to see if visible') within the 'landing.js' else if and if statement within the event listener function and nothing is seen on the console.
document.querySelector('#darkToggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === '1'){
      localStorage.setItem('darkmode', '0')
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('darkmode')   
      console.log('testing to see if visible') 
  }
  else if(localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === '0'){
      localStorage.setItem('darkmode', '1')
      document.documentElement.classList.add('darkmode')
      console.log('testing to see if visible')
  }
  });


If there are not any errors in the console either, check the Network tab to see if the script is actually loaded. If it's loaded correctly, check that there's no transparent elements covering the button, or any captured click events preventing propagation, or some CSS preventing pointer events on the button.
